# Attaching gun to animated character

Tags: animation

I have a character mesh I downloaded from blendswap, and autorigged / animated using mixamo.

I'd like to add a prop to the character, in this case a rifle. What's the easiest and most reliable way to place a weapon in the hands of my animated character?

I don't need to rig the weapon up to my character or anything, I just want to place a weapon in his hands (which are already animated to hold a weapon).

Comment: Select the weaponmodel and the character -> ctrl+j -> edit mode -> move to the right position.

Comment: no you do *not* want to join the gun mesh to the character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the gun, then shift-select the bone for the hand on the mesh and then go ctrl + P > bone. the gun should then move with the bone.

Comment: but I can't select just the hand bone, I select the gun then if I select any bone it will select all the bones

Comment: nvm I just did it in pose mode